# Windows phone Automation Test Soluction

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, automated-tests, ranorex

well. For a single module in terms of regression testing In order to improve the efficiency of the introduction of the concept of automated testing. Unfortunately, there is no any application for Windows phone Application of automated testing tools have been used in Silverlight-Ranorex test automation tools , spent some time trying to run through Ranorex test automation in the WP. that there are many applications and testing tools between the many uncontrollable problems.
First, let's look at the application installation process of implementation now only through the Application Development Tool to deploy on a real machine:

If we automate this process. The question arises how to not use the Application Development Tool of the XAP package installed on the simulator or a real machine? The same for the simulator control how to control and run the code automatically XAP package?
I found a solution:
http://www.cnblogs.com/chenkai/archive/2012/01/10/2318221.html.

My question: is there have other way about windows phone Automation TEst?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but can't you use the Windows Phone emulator?

Comment: yeah this soluction i found is base on Windows phone Emulator. is there have any other way for Automation Test about Windows phone Application ?Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this automation test framework https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework

I've heard good things about it. ;)